# c# sockets check for incoming connections and accept only one connection at a time

Tags: c#, sockets

Let's assume that I have a basic C# socket server.

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(8888);
listener.Start();

Socket clientSocket = listener.AcceptSocket();
```

This would accept the first connection that's coming from a client.

However, say we have 10 incoming connections. I do not wish to accept all 10 connections, I want to have a list of all the pending connections and choose **one** connection that I will accept and exchange data with - we can assume that I can identify them by their IP addresses. After the exchange is done, I will close the socket and pick a different connection to exchange data with.
I don't need to have more than 1 active connection since I'll be serving one client at a time.

Is such a feat possible? Or do I have to accept all of them and thread my way through them?

EDIT: Client timeout is not a problem. The clients are programmed to periodically retry their connection in case of a timeout.

**EDIT2:**
I have managed to find a similar question after quite a bit of searching. It seems like you cannot differentiate the clients until you accept their connection. Here's the question:
[How to reject a connection attempt in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104663/how-to-reject-a-connection-attempt-in-c)
I thought I could at least tell the IP address from which the connection attempts are coming from, but it seems like it's not possible until I connect to the clients. Looks like I'll be threading my way through the clients after all.

Comment: You can do this by accepting and then closing the connection, but the waiting connections will eventually time out if you don't get to them in time.

Comment: @nhouser9 the clients are programmed to retry their connection attempt after a timeout so this is not a problem in my case. I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Then there is no real issue other than performance - your clients may be waiting for quite some time if the server performs lengthy calculations. However, otherwise, nothing is stopping you from accepting a connection, closing it, and accepting a new connection.

Comment: @nhouser9 you're saying I could just accept a client, check if it's the one I want and close the connection if it's not? that's not really ideal because if the same client attempts to reconnect I might end up him connecting to me quite frequently. and it sounds like it can get really messy the more clients I have.  
or did I misunderstand what you were suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

You do not accept all connections, only **one**. You can just perform `AcceptSocket`, handle your client, and then disconnect and accept another one, e.g. in a `while(listener.Pending())` loop.

Comment: yes, but that gives me no control over which client I interact with. I can accept the connection and close it if it's not the client I want, but that can cause serious problems of the same machine connecting to me over and over again. to make you understand, these clients are machines of mine that are waiting for me to exchange data with them. I want to send instructions to them one at a time. the machines know my IP, I do not know theirs and I cannot guarantee their router lets them act as servers (port forwarding or DMZ). that is why I need to be the server and they need to be the clients.

Comment: "not the client you want" what prevents you from serving a client when it just connected?

Comment: the fact that I don't need the client which just connected. I'm terribly sorry if I didn't make my question clear enough. look - a normal approach would be to accept all 10 clients (from my example) and write to one of them at a time. just like a messenger, but only between client and server. I'm asking if it's possible to avoid maintaining those 10 concurrent connections and just accept one of them - the client (machine) I need.