# How to set server listen a specific client

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm building a server by socket C#, my server listen all IP and anybody in LAN can connect to my server but now i need my server just listen to some IP that I allowed before, i have tried to search many tutorials but have not found the answer. hope someones have the answer
Thanks all.

Comment: You might read about rejecting clients: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104663/how-to-reject-a-connection-attempt-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method isn't that great, what about if your PCs are getting their address via DHCP and that address can change, or new computers need to be added\removed to\from your "White List"

I would have used a dedicated secure VPN and only the PCs I would like to connect will be able to connect to that VPN.

If this is too complex IT wise, I would do some other authentication method over the socket, send some scrambled key that only the PCs you want to connect would have. For that read a little bit about Private\Public key. Take into consideration that in that method you are open yourself to DoS attacks.
The question is what is the level of security\authenticity you need in your organization.

A firewall with strict access roles from specific clients to specific port is also an option.

As I say, it all depends on the security level your client requires, his security policy and regulations in the industry also.

Enjoy

Comment: we are building a transfer system in small bank, so what authentication method should i use ?

Comment: I'm not a security specialist, but it sound like you need a strict security policy, I would consult with your IT department about the network topology and about defining a dedicated VPN for the group of computers that need to have access to the specific server(s). A firewall on the given server(s) is also and option , where you define that only a set of predefined clients can access specific port (if you have some expert in firewalls configuration you can also define the specific protocol maybe)